# Is there a acceptable replacement for Poisson regression for this case?

Tags: r, regression, poisson-regression, regression-strategies

I am very much a novice.

I am trying to model a data that contains non-integers and zero values.

The data contains the number of prescriptions written per county versus the number of overdose deaths per county.  Both are measured at "per thousand people."

```
> head(cv)
  Prescriptions Death.Rate
1        1201.9 0.12677485
2         666.9 0.07490745
3         711.1 0.05925575
4         728.9 0.04346787
5         655.3 0.12668491
6         737.4 0.00000000
```

About one-third of the counties do not have any overdose deaths.  Hence the zeros.  For this reason, I started to try Poisson regression only to realize it cannot take non-integers (which all of the prescription rates are).

After much searching, I have not found an appropriate regression type.

Comment: Sorry but the zero here is clearly wrong right? You cannot have 0.0 deaths. Can you?

Comment: I believe Poisson regression can be carried out [even with a non-integral response](https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/).  Whether that's appropriate for your analysis is another matter.  Why not express the death rate as the actual count of deaths and the number of people at risk for death, as is usually done in Poisson regression?

Comment: @usεr11852, Yes, 0 is correct.  Sorry, I should have specified that it is the number of overdose deaths per 1,000 people per county per year.  ("County" means a region in a state in the U.S.)

Comment: @RADO: No problem. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @whuber: I cannot count the actual number of deaths because I am trying to compare counties with populations ranging from 5,000 to 400,000.

Comment: @RADO do you expect a generally smoothing varying effect so counties who are close latit/longit.-wise to have similar rates or not?

Comment: Hit it with a Gaussian first. Gaussians are decent approximations to Poisson when the counts are high (40+). Run basic diagnostics, residuals plots, etc. and then revisit this question. As it stands you do not need to consider a Poisson or something like a Beta (cause after all only 1000 people per 1000 people can die!)

Comment: On the contrary, you *can* count the numbers of deaths: multiply the death rates by the county sizes.  Use the county sizes as *offsets* in the Poisson regression.  @usεr11852 Most people would not consider zero deaths to be "high" and certainly the Gaussian approximation is always poor in such cases.

Comment: @whuber: Apologies, I did not mean that 0 deaths to be "high". Why would I ever do that? What you be "low" in that case? Resurrections? :) Anyway in my mind, a Gaussian is often a good approximation to a Poisson when the data have a high mean (40+). The mean seems quite higher than 0 per 1000 people...

Comment: @whuber: Say I do count the deaths.  Is it wise to compare a count to a rate?  If it is not wise, can I also "offset" the prescription variable?, i.e. offset(deaths) ~ offset(prescriptions)

Comment: It's unlikely you will be comparing counts to anything--but it depends on the (unstated) purpose of your analysis.  One would naturally surmise you are interested (in some way) in the underlying death *rates* and that you might be comparing them to each other or to some kind of criterion: that's a comparison of a rate to a rate.

Comment: @whuber: In your previous comment before last,  I thought you were suggesting that I count the deaths.  So then wouldn't I be comparing counts to something?  Or did I misinterpret your reason for counting the deaths?

Comment: You will likely use your model to compare *rates*.  The rates are parameters of interest whereas the deaths are *data* that give you information about the underlying rates.

Comment: @whuber: What if my only option is to compare death rates to prescription rates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a log transformation would help excpet you have some 0's. There is support for applying a small constant and then doing a log transformation when you have 0's in your data (https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/transformations/).